# Attributing a different css styling class to a already existing css class

Tags: css, class

Please see the code below:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div id="logo" class="grid_3" class="**bigEntrance**">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

In this case, I want to animate the logo by using the css cheat sheet. The class grid_3 is already assigned in the frameworks (I'm using Cool Kitten Parallax) style sheet. 
The class bigEntrance is the ready-made class given by the css cheat sheet and I've included this inside the div id.

Now in order to use this effect what is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To apply two classes to an element just separate them with a space

```
<div id="logo" class="grid_3 bigEntrance">
```